# Cordova app preload files into cordovoa.file.dataDirectory?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugin-file, datadirectory

For the longest time I have preloaded specific files into my cordova app using the `cordova.file.applicationDirectory`.  To date, these files have only been read-only, but now I need to update these files while the app is running...but the `applicationDirectory` is a read-only folder on both Android and iOS.  So I need to move the preloaded files to another location.

I want to change the directory of these preloaded file to `dataDirectory` (or to another folder that is read-write).  However, preloaded files on Android were added to the ../platforms/android/assets folder, and on iOS, via Xcode, I simply just added them to the root of the project.  After that on both OSs I can access the read-only files with `applicationDirectory`.

However, where do I manually add the files to the project so they get preloaded into the `cordova.file.dataDirectory`?

The `cordova-plugin-file` docs show that on Android the `dataDirectory` is mapped to `/data/data/<app-id>/files` and on iOS it is mapped to `~/Library/Application Support/<bundle-id>/files` - but those are device mappings, after the app is installed.  What are the project directories, the project folders that I add those files to so they are preloaded in the `dataDirectory` upon app install?

Comment: You cannot force an installation where you end up with files in `/data/data/<app-id>/files`. You have to copy them to that location at run time.

Comment: @greenapps : translation: you are saying files can not be preloaded as assets into the `dataDirectory`?  If so, besides, the `dataDirectory` are there any other read-write folder locations that files/assets can be preinstalled into?